# "error: NSInternalInconsistencyException - Invalid parameter not satisfying: cgsEvent.type > 0 && cgsEvent.type <= kCGSLastEventType"

Tags: python, cocoa

Sometimes, mostly on heavy load, I am getting these errors:

```
2013-04-23 23:53:13.595 MusicPlayer[74705:6303] unrecognized type is -2
2013-04-23 23:53:14.686 MusicPlayer[74705:6303] *** Assertion failure in -[NSEvent _initWithCGSEvent:eventRef:], /SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-1187.37/AppKit.subproj/NSEvent.m:1348
2013-04-24 00:40:47.358 MusicPlayer[74705:6303] unrecognized type is -2
2013-04-24 00:40:47.561 MusicPlayer[74705:6303] *** Assertion failure in -[NSEvent _initWithCGSEvent:eventRef:], /SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-1187.37/AppKit.subproj/NSEvent.m:1348
2013-04-24 00:42:49.016 MusicPlayer[74705:6303] unrecognized type is -2
2013-04-24 00:42:49.017 MusicPlayer[74705:6303] *** Assertion failure in -[NSEvent _initWithCGSEvent:eventRef:], /SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-1187.37/AppKit.subproj/NSEvent.m:1348
2013-04-24 00:42:53.689 MusicPlayer[74705:6303] unrecognized type is -2
2013-04-24 00:42:53.689 MusicPlayer[74705:6303] *** Assertion failure in -[NSEvent _initWithCGSEvent:eventRef:], /SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-1187.37/AppKit.subproj/NSEvent.m:1348
2013-04-24 00:43:01.091 MusicPlayer[74705:6303] unrecognized type is -2
2013-04-24 00:43:01.091 MusicPlayer[74705:6303] *** Assertion failure in -[NSEvent _initWithCGSEvent:eventRef:], /SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-1187.37/AppKit.subproj/NSEvent.m:1348
2013-04-24 00:43:06.840 MusicPlayer[74705:6303] unrecognized type is -2
2013-04-24 00:43:06.840 MusicPlayer[74705:6303] *** Assertion failure in -[NSEvent _initWithCGSEvent:eventRef:], /SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-1187.37/AppKit.subproj/NSEvent.m:1348
EXCEPTION
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/az/Programmierung/music-player/mac/build/Release/MusicPlayer.app/Contents/Resources/Python/mediakeys.py", line 71, in runEventsCapture
    line: Quartz.CFRunLoopRun()
    locals:
      Quartz = <local> <module 'Quartz' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/Quartz/__init__.py'>
      Quartz.CFRunLoopRun = <local> <objc.function 'CFRunLoopRun' at 0x1027dfb30>
error: NSInternalInconsistencyException - Invalid parameter not satisfying: cgsEvent.type > 0 && cgsEvent.type <= kCGSLastEventType
EXCEPTION
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/az/Programmierung/music-player/mac/build/Release/MusicPlayer.app/Contents/Resources/Python/mediakeys.py", line 71, in runEventsCapture
    line: Quartz.CFRunLoopRun()
    locals:
      Quartz = <local> <module 'Quartz' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/Quartz/__init__.py'>
      Quartz.CFRunLoopRun = <local> <objc.function 'CFRunLoopRun' at 0x1027dfb30>
error: NSInternalInconsistencyException - Invalid parameter not satisfying: cgsEvent.type > 0 && cgsEvent.type <= kCGSLastEventType
EXCEPTION
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/az/Programmierung/music-player/mac/build/Release/MusicPlayer.app/Contents/Resources/Python/mediakeys.py", line 71, in runEventsCapture
    line: Quartz.CFRunLoopRun()
    locals:
      Quartz = <local> <module 'Quartz' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/Quartz/__init__.py'>
      Quartz.CFRunLoopRun = <local> <objc.function 'CFRunLoopRun' at 0x1027dfb30>
error: NSInternalInconsistencyException - Invalid parameter not satisfying: cgsEvent.type > 0 && cgsEvent.type <= kCGSLastEventType
new song: Tiestö - Reepublic, 00:15, mp3, 125 kbit/s, 233 KB
EXCEPTION
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/az/Programmierung/music-player/mac/build/Release/MusicPlayer.app/Contents/Resources/Python/mediakeys.py", line 71, in runEventsCapture
    line: Quartz.CFRunLoopRun()
    locals:
      Quartz = <local> <module 'Quartz' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/Quartz/__init__.py'>
      Quartz.CFRunLoopRun = <local> <objc.function 'CFRunLoopRun' at 0x1027dfb30>
error: NSInternalInconsistencyException - Invalid parameter not satisfying: cgsEvent.type > 0 && cgsEvent.type <= kCGSLastEventType
EXCEPTION
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/az/Programmierung/music-player/mac/build/Release/MusicPlayer.app/Contents/Resources/Python/mediakeys.py", line 71, in runEventsCapture
    line: Quartz.CFRunLoopRun()
    locals:
      Quartz = <local> <module 'Quartz' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/Quartz/__init__.py'>
      Quartz.CFRunLoopRun = <local> <objc.function 'CFRunLoopRun' at 0x1027dfb30>
error: NSInternalInconsistencyException - Invalid parameter not satisfying: cgsEvent.type > 0 && cgsEvent.type <= kCGSLastEventType
EXCEPTION
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/az/Programmierung/music-player/mac/build/Release/MusicPlayer.app/Contents/Resources/Python/mediakeys.py", line 71, in runEventsCapture
    line: Quartz.CFRunLoopRun()
    locals:
      Quartz = <local> <module 'Quartz' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/Quartz/__init__.py'>
      Quartz.CFRunLoopRun = <local> <objc.function 'CFRunLoopRun' at 0x1027dfb30>
error: NSInternalInconsistencyException - Invalid parameter not satisfying: cgsEvent.type > 0 && cgsEvent.type <= kCGSLastEventType
```

The related code:

```
    import AppKit, Quartz
    from AppKit import NSSystemDefined
    pool = AppKit.NSAutoreleasePool.alloc().init()

    self.runLoopRef = Quartz.CFRunLoopGetCurrent()

    while True:
        # https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html
        tap = Quartz.CGEventTapCreate(
            Quartz.kCGSessionEventTap, # Quartz.kCGSessionEventTap or kCGHIDEventTap
            Quartz.kCGHeadInsertEventTap, # Insert wherever, we do not filter
            Quartz.kCGEventTapOptionDefault, #Quartz.kCGEventTapOptionListenOnly,
            Quartz.CGEventMaskBit(NSSystemDefined), # NSSystemDefined for media keys
            self.eventTap,
            None
        )
        assert tap

        # Create a runloop source and add it to the current loop
        runLoopSource = Quartz.CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(None, tap, 0)
        Quartz.CFRunLoopAddSource(
            self.runLoopRef,
            runLoopSource,
            Quartz.kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
        )

        # Enable the tap
        Quartz.CGEventTapEnable(tap, True)

        try:
            # and run! This won't return until we exit or are terminated.
            Quartz.CFRunLoopRun()
        except Exception:
            # I got this one here once:
            # error: NSInternalInconsistencyException - Invalid parameter not satisfying: cgsEvent.type > 0 && cgsEvent.type <= kCGSLastEventType
            sys.excepthook(*sys.exc_info())
            continue # rerun

        # this is a regular quit
        break

    del pool
```

The exception mostly comes along with a hang of the GUI thread (which is the main reason why I don't just want to ignore it - because it can be very notable).

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1145465), I got the helpful information bit that says:

> Actually an event type CGEventType is defined in CGEventType.h as
>   unsigned 32-bit integer. So your -2 is actually 0xFFFFFFFE. In
>   CGEventType.h that's defined as kCGEventTapDisabledByTimeout. There's
>   a comment just about this that says:
>
> ```
>   /* Out of band event types. These are delivered to the event tap callback
>      to notify it of unusual conditions that disable the event tap. */
>   kCGEventTapDisabledByTimeout = 0xFFFFFFFE,
>   kCGEventTapDisabledByUserInput = 0xFFFFFFFF
> ```
>
> So it looks like
>   your event tap is timing out. That's why your not getting anymore
>   events after this.

In Python, in your event tap, you can check for this case like this:

```
def eventTap(self, proxy, type_, event, refcon):
    if type_ < 0 or type_ > 0x7fffffff:
        # handle it ...
```

Note that the event tap is disabled after you got such an event type. So you might want to restart your event loop.